# SQL Query matching same values in same column based on criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL as follows.

| donorId | amount | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 787 | 9.5 | 2022 |
| 567 | 7.9 | 2021 |
| 787 | 30 | 2022 |
| 456 | 2.5 | 2022 |
| 567 | 26 | 2022 |
| 456 | 26 | 2022 |

I need to find all donors who made at least two constructive in 2022(787, 456). there is also an issue: I can't use HAVING in the query. How to do this?

Comment: Add the desired result to your question.  Can you have sub-queries?

Comment: Hi, It should be 787 & 456

Comment: Do your table have primary key?

Comment: You must have a primary key column? please include it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is example how to do this without having in your query, using subqueries

```
declare
  @year int = '2022'

select
  x.donorId
from (
  select
    count(1) c,
    t.donorId donorId
  from yourtable t
  where t.year = @year
  group by
    t.donorId
) x
where x.c > 1
```